# Excel. Results based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, formatting, criteria

I need help with a probably complex IF statements.

I have data such as:
[image: Statistics]

From this i need to return the results based on quite a few criteria.
In the BH column I need the criteria to match this:

If it's due 6 or more days and it's >40% result is red box and a number 0.

If it's due 6 or more days and it's <40%, but the majority (80%) of it is Due >30 days, the result is a red box and a number 0.

If it's due 6 or more days and it's <5% result is a yellow box and a number 10.

If it's not due at all (Not due = 100%) the result is a green box and a number 15.

All the other possibilities is the orange category and the returnable number should be 5.

*Edited. My solution:*

```
=IF(BA4=1;15;IF(SUM(BC4:BE4)<0,05;10;IF(SUM(BC4:BE4)>0,4;0;IF(AND(SUM(BC4:BE4)<0,4;BE4>0,8);0;5))))
```

*It seems that I managed to do the formula like this, but is the sequence correct?*

Comment: IF() will take may criteria in the logical test. iif(and(A1>=6,B1>40),0) where A1 and B1 are the items you are concerned with. There are examples on here with checking dates etc

Comment: =IF(BA4=1;15;IF(SUM(BC4:BE4)<0,05;10;IF(SUM(BC4:BE4)>0,4;0;IF(AND(SUM(BC4:BE4)<0,4;BE4>0,8);0;5))))

It seems that I managed to do the formula like this, but is the sequence correct?